# I'm looking for a text editor just like this stack overflow textArea editor that returns non- html using EJS

Tags: node.js, markdown, ejs, editor, wysiwyg

textArea = This text is **bold**

expectedOutput = This text is **bold**

output = < p > This text is  bold < /strong >< /p >

Is there an editor that can enable me render the *expected output*?